# How to perform Braintree transaction after receiving Nonce?

Tags: flutter, paypal, braintree, google-pay, braintree-sandbox

I am using [Flutter_braintree plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_braintree) to integrate PayPal and Google Pay in my flutter app . I am able to get Nonce after performing BraintreeDropInRequest. I don't know How to process this Nonce for transaction. If there is any documentation please help me with it. May be I am doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server uses the nonce from the client to create a transaction. Read the [Braintree documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/transactions) for whatever environment your server is.